# Magento get the products from a specific category with name, image and description

Tags: php, magento

How I can get the products from a specific category with name, image and description?

Michael

Answer (score 0):

```
 $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                       ->addCategoryFilter(CATEGORY ID);

 foreach($productCollection AS $_product)
 {
     echo $_product->getName();

     echo $_product->getImageUrl();

     echo $_product-> getDescription();
 }
```

Comment: Hi Sankar. I tried your code but that breaks my page. Of course i have changed the CATEGORY ID. Do you have other ideas?